# Error compiling Cuda - expected primary-expression

Tags: c++, cuda, gpgpu

this program seems be fine but I still getting an erro, some suggestion?

Program:

```
#include "dot.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int *a, *b, *c;
    int *dev_a, *dev_b, *dev_c;
    int size = N * sizeof(int);

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int));

    a = (int *)malloc (size);
    b = (int *)malloc (size);
    c = (int *)malloc (sizeof(int));

    random_ints(a, N);
    random_ints(b, N);

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    int res = N/THREADS_PER_BLOCK;
    dot<<< res, THREADS_PER_BLOCK >>> (dev_a, dev_b, dev_c);
    //helloWorld<<< dimGrid, dimBlock >>>(d_str);

    cudaMemcpy (c, dev_c, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    free(a); free(b); free(c);
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_c);
    return 0;
}
```

the error:

> DotProductCuda.cpp:27: error: expected primary-expression before `'<'` token
>   DotProductCuda.cpp:27: error: expected primary-expression before `'>'` token

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `<<< >>>` syntax for calling a kernel is not standard C or C++. Those calls must be in a file compiled by the NVCC compiler. Those files are normally named with a .cu extension. Other API calls to CUDA such as `cudaMalloc` can be in regular .c or .cpp files.

Comment: Answer my question about <<>>, but now I'm getting `DotProductCuda.cu(26): error: a host function call can not be configured` Some idea?

Comment: Yes, you haven't declared dot as a kernel to nvcc, so it is treating it as an implicitly defined host function.

Comment: I found. I'm not declaring dot as __global__ method. Cuda functions are something like `__global__ void dot....`

Answer (score 5):

`nvcc` uses the file extension to determine how to process the contents of the file. If you have CUDA syntax inside the file, it must have a .cu extension, otherwise nvcc will simply pass the file untouched to the host compiler, resulting in the syntax error you are observing.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the compiler cannot recognize the <<<,>>> syntax. I have no experience with CUDA, but I guess you need to compile this file with a special compiler and not an ordinary C compiler.

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you use a host function (printf for example) inside kernel?